# LabVIEW: How to store jpeg from an array of data

Tags: jpeg, labview

Hi I have a 16 bit image and I know its size, image depth, mask. image tpe, rectangle (left, top, right, and bottom). I don't have IMAQ so I have to write my own subvi to save jpeg image.

I can use "Write JPEG file.vi". Is it even possible to construct my own image cluster and write a jpeg image with "Write JPEG file.vi" ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, the image cluster is just a regular cluster that you need to supply with the correct data. The only complicated thing in there is the image data variable but that is well documented in the help of the "Write JPEG file.vi". Only the 16 bit part might be troublesome since this is not supported.

An example of how you would read an image and write it via the normal way and if you create your own image data from the read image. Comparing the two images shows that it is exactly the same.

[image]